# How to use git to download a project

Tags: git

I'm new to git and can anyone tell me how to download this project? I don't know why the author writes 'replace “kai” with your user name', but I just followed this instruction and used my user name. However, it prompts me to type in the password while I didn't set up any password. If I keep the original user name, it will also prompt me to enter the password. All what I did is

```
git config --global user.name luming
git config --global user.email \myemail
git clone luming@fishercat.sr.unh.edu:/srv/git/psc 
git clone kai@fishercat.sr.unh.edu:/srv/git/psc
```

The corresponding output is

```
luming@fishercat.sr.unh.edu's password:
kai@fishercat.sr.unh.edu's password:
```

And the instruction from the website writes:

```
//Get the code (replace “kai” with your user name):

[kai@mbpro tmp]$ git clone kai@fishercat.sr.unh.edu:/srv/git/psc
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/kai/tmp/psc/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 918, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (523/523), done.
remote: Total 918 (delta 626), reused 581 (delta 384)
Receiving objects: 100% (918/918), 308.78 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (626/626), done.
```

I just want to download it and use it. So can anyone tell me how to download this project? Thanks in advance! PS: the web link is http://fishercat.sr.unh.edu/psc/installation.html#installing-the-code-from-the-git-repo

Comment: From the output it looks like your clone worked.  Did anything appear in your /Users/kai/tmp/psc/ directory?

Comment: Oh, the output is the instruction on the website. My output actually is something like "Password for luming@fishercat.sr.unh.edu:" and "Password for kai@fishercat.sr.unh.edu:". And I don't know any password...

Comment: Do you have an ssh account on the fishercat.sr.unh.edu server? The username the instructions is referring to is the username you use to login to that server.

Comment: @Charlie Nope, I don't have an ssh account on that server. So the problem is I must have an ssh account on that server to access the project?

Comment: For the way you are trying to get to the repository, yes you need an ssh account / keys. Alternatively they could expose the repository over [a different protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html), but that'd be up to the project owners.

Comment: I just got an account and the key! Thanks for your help!@Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have access to that server, may be key exchange or may be password to that server. when you using username@url.git , you specify your username in that server and the url for the git repository (url.git). therefore according to the information (I also tried out) you need to have username and password to that server or you have to have a public or private key exchange with that server. (do you have a private or public key ?)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just got a userid & passwd and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code from 
http://fishercat.sr.unh.edu/psc/psc-1.94.tar.gz

Comment: The asker specifically wants to clone the repo in `git`.

Comment: That tar file missed some files so I have to download it using git. Anyway, thanks for your reply~ ^_^